# tomcat-maven-plugin in GWT project. What is the difference between: org.codehaus.mojo and org.apache.tomcat.maven plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, gwt

I am trying to set up `tomcat server` for `gwt` application. I would like to configure server to update my `server side code changes immediately`.

While looking for some helpful examples over the web, I found that there are to plugins for maven.

One from:
`org.codehaus.mojo` (which also provide plugin for `gwt` in `maven` echosystem).

And second from: `org.apache.tomcat.maven`.

What is the difference between them? Which one should I choose for:
**GWT 2.7 Maven Project**. I will develope app in **Eclipse IDE**. So I would like to have good integration with it to. F.e.: the Eclipse tab/view "Servers".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.2/

> This is the new home for the Tomcat Maven Plugin (previously hosted at Codehaus).

The CodeHaus Mojo (now MojoHaus) Tomcat Maven Plugin is obsolete.

I have Maven archetypes that use the Tomcat Maven Plugin to fire up a server for development, with automatic redeployment of the webapp when classes change, at https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes
Note that they use a different Maven Plugin for GWT than the one from MojoHaus (ex-CodeHaus Mojo), one that works much better with multi-module builds.
I've never used Eclipse WTP though (tried it and had too much trouble, probably because I didn't really know how to use it properly though) so I can't really comment, but I see no reason why it wouldn't work.

Comment: I've tried to test Your code. I've done everything like it was in read me file. I've done: `git clone https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes.git
cd gwt-maven-archetypes && mvn clean install` and then: `mvn gwt:codeserver -pl *-client -am` which gives me an error: `Could not find the selected project in the reactor: *-client -> [Help 1]` Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Could You point me the: `automatic redeployment` configuration in Maven archetypes that You use?

Comment: This is a Maven archetype, use the `mvn archetype:generate` to create a project (no need to clone the repo). And IIRC, auto-redeploy is actually the default behavior of the plugin, no need to configure anything.

Comment: Is default behavior of the plugin? What plugin and in what version? You have so many pom.xml files so I don't know where to look for it.

Comment: If you create a project out of the archetype, you only get 4 POMs (a root POM and 3 modules). It then uses https://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.2/run-mojo-features.html. I use a context file with `reloadable="true"`, there's also a plugin property [`contextReloadable`](https://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.2/tomcat7-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html#contextReloadable).

Comment: Great answer. Thanks. I didn't know about it. I will dive into it right now.